# Do you pronounce the "い" sound in yakisoba [やきそば]?

Tags: pronunciation

The dish yakisoba is clearly written as やきそば or 焼きそば.  When I hear native speakers speak it, it sounds to me like the "い" sound in "き" is silent.  I've heard it pronounced like "yak-soba".  Is there a reason for this and is it correct to pronounce it like "yak-soba" or should I pronounce it like the hirigana is written?

Comment: But the consonant /k/ is still palatalized as it is in き. In IPA it would be [kʲ] rather than just [k]. Native speakers would hear "yaksoba" as やくそば if it's pronounced the way English speakers would expect it to be pronounced from that spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a textbook case of [devoicing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ulhd9fl2Gug). I am not at all well-versed in the rules and exceptions to this phenomenon, but some information can be found [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology#Devoicing).

Note that there are certain regions and dialects of Japan where devoicing is not observed. If you hear a word pronounced not like what you would have expected, always try to consult a dictionary like [this one](https://sakura-paris.org/dict/NHK%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E7%99%BA%E9%9F%B3%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8/suffix/%E7%84%BC%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9D%E3%81%B0) (In this link, devoicing of the キ is represented by a discontinuous circle around the katakana).

Answer (score 1):

The vowel of the second syllable does appear to be devoiced, compare the pronunciation of 競う and 生蕎麦, where the 'i' of the initial 'ki' is quite definitely devoiced.